# how to save edittext when back pressed to previous activity

Tags: android, listview

may be my question wrong.but when i click on item in listview i open other activty to edit the item name text after that when i back press it was saving but not renaming to the listview.so please help me.

listview class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_view);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.invalidateViews();
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    final List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
       s.add(bt.getName());
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s));
    //listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    //listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt,
                long paramLong) {
       // TextView select_text=(TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.select_text);

            String name=s.get(paramInt);
            Intent i = new Intent(SettingOptionActivity.this, EditPreview.class);     
            i.putExtra("name", name);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);

            //Log.v("____string name________", "__________"+name);
            //loadSavedPreferences(s.get(paramInt));
    }              

    }); 

}
```

and the following class is to edit the name of item

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
    edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.device_text);

  //  edittext.setText(val);    
    loadSavedPreferences();

}
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    /*SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
*/   Intent i = getIntent();
       String val = "";

       if(i.hasExtra("name"))
             val = i.getStringExtra("name");

    edittext.setText(val);
    Log.v("___________edittext", "_______________"+edittext.getText());
    }
    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
      //      .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences   sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences(
                  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
     Log.v("__________key", "_______________"+key);
     Log.v("___________value", "_______________"+value);
    //edittext.setText(editor.toString());
     Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("name", edittext.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    editor.commit();
    }
    public void saveData(){
    savePreferences("name", edittext.getText().toString());
     Log.v("___________edittext", "_______________"+edittext.getText().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        saveData();

    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

so please check and help me.

Comment: May be you need to  refresh your listvistview in your onResume() method of previous activity when you press back

Comment: what does your `saveData()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You may try another way, instead of SharedPreference.

// First Save the Text

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState )
{
      super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );
      outState.putInt( "textValue", editText.getText().toString() );
}
```

// Load the Text

```
@Override 
public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
      ....

      if ( savedInstanceState != null )
      {
           editText.setText ( savedInstanceState.getString ( "textValue" ) );
      }

      ....
}
```

Comment: Hmm, correct me if I am wrong, but in this case the state is saved only in the second, **"edit activity"**, but the `ListView` item string is not updated this way, as it resides in the **"first activity"**. Moreover, `onSaveInstanceState` is not intended to persist valuable data, only the instance state (although these are quite the same, frequently).

Comment: @Drew Yes, you are korrect, but I answer based on the looking question title. Its my mistake.

Comment: He is opening details in other activity not in same .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but you could make your

```
final List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

=> public static List<String> s; (Before the constructor)
```

and your ListView Activity's onCreate()

```
s = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In your EditName Activity you modify the ListView.s. -listitems name attribute and then on your ListView's onResume method you call:

Edit 2:

Before onCreate:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
```

In onCreate:

```
this.aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s));
listView.setAdapter(this.aa);
```

In onResume:

```
this.aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hi, but when add mBluetoothAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onResume() i got this error The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type BluetoothAdapter.

Comment: again i got this The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type BluetoothAdapter.

Comment: Edited my answer. was supposed to be the ArrayAdapter.. not BluetoothAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

try this in listview class:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int   paramInt,
            long paramLong) {
   // TextView select_text=(TextView)viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.select_text);

        String name=s.get(paramInt);
        Intent i = new Intent(SettingOptionActivity.this, EditPreview.class);     
        i.putExtra("name", name);
        i.putExtra("position", paramInt);
        startActivityForResult(i,0);

        //Log.v("____string name________", "__________"+name);
        //loadSavedPreferences(s.get(paramInt));
}              

});
```

and implement callback method :

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        int position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        String newName = data.getIntExtra("name");
        s.get(0).replace(oldname, newName );
        yourAdapterObject.notifyDatasetChanged();
     }
```

}

And in your name edit class pass position as you have got from intent.

Comment: mBluetoothadapter is not refreshing.

Comment: it was not updating the listview.i got same name as in first only.please help me.